# Protractor tests on BrowserStack iPhone devices are not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jasmine, protractor, karma-runner

For some reason the iPhone devices are never able to load the url requested by Protractor, they always show a blank page. It tries to load the url several times and then gives up.

The other BrowerStack devices all seem to work, including Windows, Android, and Safari/Macbook.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

For reference, we're using Protractor v2.2.0 (have not been able to updated because we're stuck in an old version of NodeJS, but we could try if that is the cause of the issue).

Comment: Does the same site/app work when tested manually?  I wonder if it's an issue with something in your site and the BrowserStack iPhone or only when trying to execute tests?

Comment: Yep, works manually. I just emailed BrowserStack support and they said it's a limitation of appium with iphone and "execute_async". But when I search those topics on Google I only find a few git issues from over a year ago that seem to have been resolved.

Comment: Encountered same issue and got the same reply from them.

Comment: @zalow517 Yeah, that's why I posted this question on StackOverflow. Couldn't find anyone else talking about, but seems like quite an oversight not to mention this in the JavaScript documentation on BrowerStack documentation.